# Function call doesn't display cout

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, overloading

Hello I've written a program to calculate the ending balance of a bank account. I've created an overloaded function to add the deposits to the starting balance, one for an interest amount and one without any interest. Currently, the function call does not display any value.

Any input as to why this happens would be greatly appreciated! And yes, I have stepped through the code line by line and explained it to my rubber duck.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 25;
const int sentinel = -999;


int main(){
    void balanceAccount(double, int, double[]);
    void balanceAccount(double, int, double[], double);
    double balance = 0.0, interest = 0.0, num = 0.0, total = 0.0;
    double deposit[SIZE] = {};
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter starting balance: $";
    cin >> balance;

    while (num != sentinel && count < SIZE)
    {
        cout << "Enter up to 25 deposits, or -999 to quit: " << endl;
        cin >> num;
        if (num != sentinel){
            deposit[count] = num;
            count++;
        }
        cout << "There are " << count << " deposits this week." << endl;
    }
    cout << "Test deposits: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        cout << deposit[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "Enter interest amount: ";
    cin >> interest;
    if (interest == 0.0){
        balanceAccount(balance, count, deposit);
    }
    else if (interest > 0.0){
        balanceAccount(balance, count, deposit, interest);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void balanceAccount(double bal, int ct, double dep[]){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++){
        sum += dep[i];
    }
    sum = sum + bal;

    cout << "Ending balance: $" << sum << endl;
}
void balanceAccount(double bal, int ct, double dep[], double rate){
    double interestAmount = 0.0, sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++){
        sum += dep[i];
    }
    sum = sum + bal;
    interestAmount = sum * rate;
    sum = sum + interestAmount;

    cout << "Ending balance: $" << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: You mean `interest == 0.0` not `interest = 0.0`. Also, why post only a part of your `main` function? Are we supposed to guess what you wrote?

Comment: Include in your question what it does display exactly.  Based on your code you should see `$0` but your description sounds like you are just seeing `$` followed by nothing

Comment: I thought the error was in the call of the function. It was exactly what you stated == instead of =. Strange because even if the Interest rate was greater than 0, the function wouldn't call

Comment: You should compile with some useful warnings (for GCC -Wparentheses included by -Wall would complain like this: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition in first if does not compare `interest` against value `0`, but rather assigns `0` to the `interest` variable. Result of such condition is `0` which is interpreted as false.
Next if (else-if) checks if the `interest` is positive, but since you changed it in previous condition to `0`, it is false again.

Change assignment into comparison using `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code a bit:

```
if (interest == 0)
```

Comment: Please vote to close questions that have similar errors for **a simple typographical error**.